# JS regex format & list validation

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to validate that an input is just digits and its value is not 'blacklisted'.
The expression I made is the following:

```
(?=[0-9]{3})(?=(?!^(111)|^(222)|^(333)|^(123)|^(321)\b)\b\w+)
```

I've tested it on a regex validator and works perfectly!

BUT because of framework limitations my regex is surrounded by and additional ^...& delimiters making it match with any input.

Im trying to came up with a new regex that works when surrounded by the delimiters, but Im having trouble figuring it out.

Does somebody have any idea on how to achieve this?

Comment: could you provide some sample strings and clarify where the delimiters appear?

Comment: What are the delimiters for?  Are you validating QueryString variables?

Comment: `my regex is surrounded by and additional ^...&` Is your regex surrounded by delimiters or the string you're matching?

Comment: do you mean `&` or do you mean `$`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using

```
    ^(?!111|222|333|123|321)(\d{3,})$
//  ^                                 if this is added by the framework omit
//   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^          the first 3 numbers must not match any of these groups
//                           ^^       digit
//                              ^^^^  at least 3 times
//                                  ^ followed by end of string. Again if added by framework omit
```